# PHP. Static property of child overrides parent's? Can someone explain a theory?

Tags: php

Here is the code sample. Tested in PHP 5.6, PHP 7.3.

```
class a {
    static public $prop = 'in a';
}

class b extends a {

}

a::$prop = 111;
b::$prop = 777;

print_r(a::$prop);
```

What do you think we gain?

```
a::prop = 777 (!!!)
```

How is that?

1. I know the Late Static Binding principals, but could someone point
   me to a theory, where such behavior is explained?
2. Does JAVA behave the same?
3. Does Python behave the same?

Thank you.

**[SOLUTION]**

PLlease, see my own comment below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59300364/3142281

Comment: 1. You can't dynamically define new static properties, so `b::$prop` doesn't actually exist. Define `$prop` in `b` for the expected behaviour. 2. PHP is not Java. 3. PHP is not Python.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that explicit set of $prop in class b solves the issue. But I never meet this in documentation (((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLUTION]**

I've discovered solution by my own!
Please, see the comment here: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#107965

> Unlike inheritance; if a trait has static properties, each class using
>   that trait has independent instances of those properties.

Some more words...
So, you, probably, can imagine, what inheritance problems can appear, if we always are forced to redefine static fields, extending each time.
Traits seem to solve this very laconically.

Comment: Sidenote. Inheritance refers to objects, not classes so what happens with statics does not have to conform to inheritance

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is not related to Late Static Binding. LSB can occur when you have property or function with same name, on different levels of hierarchy.

Since class `b` does not define its own static variable `$prop` when you access `b::$prop` you fall through and in fact access variable `a::$prop`. In this case both `a::$prop` and `b::$prop` refer to the same variable.

Yes, JAVA behaves the same way. I don't know how it works in Python, but I would expect same result.